# Exploring ship wrecks in Assassin's Creed Black Flag

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

When exploring ship wrecks you are attacked sometimes by sharks and eels. Is there any way to avoid these creatures? Is there a weapon that you can use that I'm just not seeing?

It seems that they can't attack me when I'm in an air barrel. But is that the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Are there other ways to avoid them**

*There are a few ways to hide from sharks*

- *Hide in the underwater grass* 
- *Go into the air barrels*
- *Go inside broken ships or other architecture. This will hide you from the sharks*
- *Get out of their line of sight*

For eels, you need to spot where they're hiding and just stay away from them.  They don't leave their hiding spots, only waiting for you to come close.

Thes are the best/only ways to hide from them

Comment: If you are hiding inside wrecks do keep an eye out for the sharp spiky corals, they'll damage you if you bump into them.